# Spring @modelattribute, how to create parameterized object

Tags: spring

I want to bind an object with `@ModelAttribute` with spring form beans, but my object takes request and a string object to initialize itself.
How can I create a parameterized object using spring `@ModelAttribute` tag.

Comment: What have you tried? Post the code to the object you are trying to initialize (and I also believe you are missing the point of binding and what a model attribute is).

Comment: Suppose, I have a @ModelAttribute Pizza pizza in my request handler method. but for creating this Pizza, I want some user provided form values and also a unique string that I want to generate at server side.

Comment: Pizza p = new Pizza ( type , uniqueString)

Comment: type will be user provided, and unique string I will generate at server side

Comment: You don't get the point of binding. Sprnig creates the object and then binds (sets properties) on the created object, those properties are the form submitted value. I don't really see how the type would be user provided. Please add some code that you expect to b e working but that isn't... Currently there is too little information (also please extend your original question with the information instead of only comments).

Comment: agree with @M.Deinum, but if the use case is to generate a unique string on server side, you can just add a generate method in the constructor of class Pizza

Comment: Or create a factory to construct those objects. Depends a little on the usecase :).

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16090547/can-i-add-value-in-a-bindingresult-before-checking-errors-in-spring/16098313#16098313